# Virtual File System with FTP

Tags: python, ftp, filesystems, uac, sftp

I've been reading through the FileSystem documentation in Python from here:
http://packages.python.org/fs/filesystems.html

After taking the time to read through it and a bit of Google-ing I didn't quite find the answer I was looking for. I was wondering if it was possible with Python, and avoiding any UAC issues on Windows, if you could 'mount' or display a file free from an FTP server inside Windows Explorer for any other applications to -read- from.

Is something this possible? What's the best approach to achieve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows explorer has built-in support for FTP.

Comment: Uhm well, on a good operating system for professionals like GNU/Linux, you could use `fuse`. I don't know about your situation, is this thing you're doing for gamers? If not, you may consider upgrading to Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Windows explorer has built-in support for FTP, [instructions with screenshots here](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/516/Setting+up+FTP+via+Windows+Explorer#gs).

> 1. Open Windows Explorer (My computer)
> 2. Right-click anywhere in the folder, and then click Add a Network Location.
> 3. This displays the Add Network Connection wizard. Click Next.
> 4. In the wizard, select Choose a custom network location, and then click Next.
> 5. Enter the name of the FTP site, with the full FTP:// in front of it, and then click Next (something like  - for example if you domain name is DOMAIN.NET the full name should look like this: ).
> 6. To use a name and password, clear the Log on anonymously check box. Type your FTP Account Username, and then click Next.
> 7. By default, the name of the shortcut is the same as the FTP address. If you want to give the shortcut a different name, type it in the Type a name for this network location box. Click Next.

You can even use it from the standard "file" dialog box. Is it enough?

[update]

> Out of curiosity, does this have support for FTPS and/or SFTP? – André Caron

@AndréCaron: I think WebDAV with SSL is supported, but no native support for SFTP or FTPS. There are extensions like [Swish](http://www.swish-sftp.org/) (opensource) or [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) (payware).

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this have support for FTPS and/or SFTP?

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-trivial matter and afaik there exist not such a thing as provide os-level functionality through some lines of magical python code.

A possible solution to emulate your intention could be to create a local webdav proxy, which maps to the ftp-server. I know there exists a feature to attach a webdav-network device to a local drive-letter, but because the last time i touched a windows system was ... - i can't even remember - i can't tell you if you might also attach a ftp-resource this way directly.

I guess looking for a solution on a python level might not be productive in a short-term perspective and even on mid/long-term's not possible without heavy tinkering on your side.

Answer (score 1):

While not a "filesystem" per-se, you can provide a [Windows Explorer Namespace Extension](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S332.aspx) which will allow the Windows explorer to browse any virtual file-system.  This is used to implement browsing of ZIP archives, for example.  Note that this does not provide a real file system drive, so it will not allow you to open the contents of this namespace extension using regular file I/O functions.

The namespace extensions are written in COM, and it is possible to [implement COM interfaces in Python](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html).

AFAIK, the only permissions you need are for installing of the namespace extension (the COM DLL, plus the namespace registration).  Everything else runs in the logged-in user's context and requires no special permissions.